# Duplicate CSS Class using insertafter when moving a css class in js, wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am moving a css class in Wordpress using insertafter in a JS script. This works fine, however the JS script is outputting duplicates of the css class? Anyone got any ideas how to fix this please?

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function() { ?>
<script>
    ( function( $ ) {
        'use strict';
        $( document ).on( 'ready', function() {
            $('.variations').insertAfter('.single_variation_wrap');
        } );
    } ( jQuery ) );
</script>
```

[image: Output Example]

Comment: This code seems to have worked. It's broken the loop anyway

Answer (score 0):

This worked.

```
(function($) {
                'use strict';
                $(document).on('ready', function() {
                    $('.variations').each(function() {
                        $(this).siblings('.single_variation_wrap').after(this);
                    });
                });
            }(jQuery));
```